# Input slideUp/slideDown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Seems like jQuery removes the value of a input fields that has been slided up and then afterwards down. Not quite sure if it's the placeholder who does it but the built in slideUp/Down seems to bug the input field.

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bc2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideUp').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideUp(1000);
    });

    $('#slideDown').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```

If you enter a value in the input field and click the slideUp button and wait till it's slided up and then click the slideDown you will see the value of the input field is missing.


Does anyone know a workaround to get a slideUp/slideDown working on the example linked?
Using google chrome if that gives an idea of why.

Comment: A quick fix would be to Put the input in a `<span>` and slide the span instead of input http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bc2/2/

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue which browser are you using?

Comment: I am getting the same issue under Chrome 20. The value is still there, it's just barely visible it seems: http://jsfiddle.net/UJFvx/7/

Comment: @AndersHolmström, Yes you are correct

Comment: @Imdad the container solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occurs when height of the input comes 0. You should change your method. Use css position with masking animate method:

[Here is demo link. You'll inspect there will be no bug with this method.](http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bc2/8/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideUp').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').stop().animate({'top':'200px'},400);
    });

    $('#slideDown').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').stop().animate({'top':'0px'},400);
    });
});​
```

html:

```
<div id="mask">
   <input id="motion" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter some text.." />
</div>
<input type="button" value="slideUp" id="slideUp" />
<input type="button" value="slideDown" id="slideDown" />​
```

css:

```
#mask { position:relative; 160px; height:25px; overflow:hidden; top:0; left:0; }
#motion { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
input { position:relative; } ​
```

Comment: This seem to be the only solution as of now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in chrome (not jQuery). It works fine in ff.

Its something related with `font-size` , I guess. Chrome does not loses `font-size` but if you set again, it works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideUp').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideUp(1000);
    });

    $('#slideDown').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideDown(1000,function(){ 
             $(this).css('font-size',$(this).css('font-size'));                
        });
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6HXkw/2/)

**EDIT:**

I see that above hack works for one time only. If you slide up/down again, it fails.

Here's a better hack.

```
.text{ 
    font-size:13px; 
}​

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideUp').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideUp(1000,function(){
               $(this).removeClass('text');        
        });
    });

    $('#slideDown').click(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').slideDown(1000,function(){    
            $(this).addClass('text');     
        });
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6HXkw/3/)

Comment: Tested in latest chrome version. Does not seem to resolve the text. placeholder is still not being displayed after slideDown and neither is text. But thanks for giving it a shot.

Comment: Can you try placing a text instead of placeholder ? Btw it works with placeholder and text both on my win7 with latest chrome