# How is this animation done?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like the way  [this little animation](https://gidsy.com/city/london/) is shown

At the very top left, when we mouse over the logo, the `Home` text is showed.

How is this possible? I check the css and did not found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece of script that does it:

```
function home_button(){
    $(".blue-arrow a")
        .mouseenter(function(){
            if($("body").hasClass("homepage")!==true){
                $(".logo").stop().animate({top:-51},200);
            }
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(".logo").stop().animate({top:0},200);
        })
        .mousedown(function(){
                $(".header-bar .light-area").css("backgroundColor","#005995");
        })
}
```

It occurs in the https://d3pvklq8xnxxh2.cloudfront.net/cache/js/base.0b56986.js file

Answer (score 9):

On the site it's achieved via javascript, but that's not necessary.

It's a simple transition:

The normal style is

```
top:0;
```

and the hover style

```
top:-51px;
```

combined with

```
transition: all 1s/*the time*/;
```

and an image like that:

```
+-------+
| Gidsy |
|       |
|  Home |
+-------+
```

Note: Transitions don't work in Internet Explorer Version 9 and less. The improved and simplified Javascript (jQuery) would be:

```
$(".blue-arrow a").hover(
     /* mouse-in */
     function(){
         $(".logo").stop().animate({top:-51},200);
     },
     /* mouse-out */
     function(){
         $(".logo").stop().animate({top:0},200);
     }
);
```

To make both versions work correctly you need a wrapping element, which has half the height of your image in question and `overflow:hidden` so that it only shows one of the images at once.

**[Here is an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/tF7nW/)** with both, JS- and CSS-version.

Comment: css3 transition does not work in ie

Comment: While this will work occasionally, the OP would be better suited to using Javascript to ensure further cross-browser compatibility until CSS transition compatible browsers begin to take the majority market share.

Comment: added a javascript solution. However I prefer css-only solutions since these transitions have graceful degradation.

Comment: if you are using jQuery; you need mask image with html tag use overflow:hidden, and you need define both css position:relative or absolute. current answer's jQuery part won't work with this css.

Comment: masking method sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627531/input-slideup-slidedown-issue/11627680#11627680

Comment: It should be noted that the `transition` solution above from @Christoph will not work on older browsers. Also, transitions still largely require browser prefixes to work at the moment, as they are considered "experimental". 

The javascript solution is better if for no other reason than that it will work for a much larger percentage of users. 

However, the information of how to prepare the image etc is sound.

Comment: @Christoph I edited to correct the compatibility. IE9 doesn't support CSS transitions either, they are introduced in IE10. (not officially released yet)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with pure CSS very easily:

```
<div class="logo"><a href="#">Text 1<br />Text 2</a></div>
```

```css
.logo {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a {
   height: 25px; 
   color: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   -o-transition: margin 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: margin 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s;
}
.logo:hover a {
   margin-top: -30px;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/mkU88705)**