# .slideDown() not working properly when using input boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that when someone selects other, extra input boxes will slide down.  My issue is, all this works except when I go to type in the input boxes nothing will go in.  I have tried to do it in IE- newest version and I am able to type.  Same thing with Firefox.  Chrome is where it is not working.  When I go into dev tools(For Chrome) and turn off a value in input box, then turn it back on I can type.

CODE: This is the code I am using for the input boxes. I do have script implemented.

```
<div class="other">testing</div>

<input type="text" class="otherbox" />
<input type="text" class="otherbox" />

<input type="text" class="otherbox"/>
<script>
$(".other").click(function () {
$(this).css({ borderStyle:"inset", cursor:"wait" });
$(".otherbox").slideDown(1000,function(){
$(this).css("border", "2px red inset")
//.filter(".otherbox")
 //.css("background", "yellow")
 //.focus();
$(".other").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
});

</script>
```

CSS code:

```
.other { background:#cfd; margin:3px; width:50px; 
text-align:center; float:left; cursor:pointer;
border:2px outset black; font-weight:bolder; }
.otherbox { display:none; width:120px; float:left; 
margin:10px; }
```

UPDATED----------------------------------------------------------

```
<html>
<body>
        <div id="MainContainer">   
            <h2 align="center">
                <u></u>
           </h2>

         <div class="FormContainer">
            <form name="theform" action="insert.php" method="post" >
                <div class="CheckBoxContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="only-thisform"/>

            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="approval" id="approval"/>

            </div><!------------------------------------END   .CheckBoxContainer ------------------------------------------->
            <br>
            <br>


<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->


<div class="DropDownSelector">

    <div class="DropdownDiscription"> </div>
</div> <!------------------------------------------END .DropDownSelector -------------------------------------------------------->

<br>
<div class="other">testing</div>

<input type="text" class="otherbox" />
<input type="text" class="otherbox" />

<input type="text" class="otherbox"/>
<script>
$(".other").click(function () {
$(this).css({ borderStyle:"inset", cursor:"wait" });
$(".otherbox").slideDown(1000,function(){
$(this).css("border", "2px red inset")
//.filter(".otherbox")
 //.css("background", "yellow")
 //.focus();
$(".other").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
});

</script>
<div class="FormBody">

    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Insurance Company Name: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="compname" id="compname" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Insurance Phone number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name ="policynum" id="policynum"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Name of the Policyholder: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="nameofPolicyholder" id="nameofPolicyholder"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policyholder mailing address: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="mailing" id="mailing"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">City: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
    <!------------------------------------------STATE SELECTION CODE ------------------------------------------->

  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onChange="submitform()">


<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner">

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield" value="">
 </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Zipcode: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Year Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="YearOfVehicle" id="YearOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Make Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="MakeOfVehicle" id="MakeOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Model Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="ModelOfVehicle" id="ModelOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Vehicle Identification Number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Vehicleid" id="Vehicleid"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Effective Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Policyeffdate" id="Policyeffdate"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Expiration Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Policyexpdate" id="Policyexpdate"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<h2>Employee Information</h2>

<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Employee Name: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Employee Company Name: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="EmployeeCompanyName" id="EmployeeCompanyName"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Agency/Franchise Number (or unique indicator): </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Agency/FranchiseNumber" id="Agency/FranchiseNumber"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Todays Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="TodaysDate" id="TodaysDate" value="



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="CheckBoxContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="correct"/>The above printed name serves to identify the employee and shows intent of the employee that the above auto insurance information given is accurate.  

            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="agree" id="agree"/>The employee identified above confirms this document has been read, reviewed and understood and subsequently authorizes it as such. 

             <br>
             <br>
             <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="understood" id="understood"/>The employee understands that if inaccurate information is discovered on the above auto insurance information table, on the employee's auto policy itself or if the auto insurance policy is cancelled for any reason, the employer will be notified. 

            </div><!------------------------------------END   .CheckBoxContainer ------------------------------------------->
            <br>




<input type="Submit" name="Submit" >

</div><!-------------------------------------------END .FormBody ------------------------------------------------------->
</form>


    </div><!--------------------------------------End .FormContainer ---------------------------------------------->

</div><!----------------------------------End #MainContainer----------------------------------->

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED----------------------------

I also just tried making a separate .php file with:

```
<div class="other">testing</div>

<input type="text" class="otherbox" />
<input type="text" class="otherbox" />

<input type="text" class="otherbox"/>
<script>
$(".other").click(function () {
$(this).css({ borderStyle:"inset", cursor:"wait" });
$(".otherbox").slideDown(1000,function(){
$(this).css("border", "2px red inset")
//.filter(".otherbox")
 //.css("background", "yellow")
 //.focus();
$(".other").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
});

</script>
```

and css style. But still no cigar.

Comment: It is better to make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that there is something else happening on this page that is impacting the inputs in question.  I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ULRSK/) and I am able to enter data into the fields in Chrome.  Try the fiddle I have provided, if it works for you, there is something else going on.

Comment: I have php code + some javascript code that takes values and auto update them

Comment: Ya the code is working but idk why it is not working for me. I'm gonna update file

Comment: What are the CSS classes, "otherbox" and "other"

Comment: used for the input box and div surrounding it.

Comment: Instead of adding the PHP, could you put the resultant HTML?  I don't have a PHP server here.  It will be easier to find the problem looking at raw HTML.

Comment: There seems to be something amiss with your "STATE SELECTION CODE" section.  Other than that, I have duplicated your code here http://jsfiddle.net/h8FSL/ and it seems to be working fine.  Are there any external CSS or JS files that might be causing the problem?

Comment: Its probably wrong because I was deleting stuff. Its fine.  Okay check out my above statement.  I created a new .php file with just the code you gave me + style.  Still will not receive text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  What version of Chrome are you running?  I am running "21.0.1180.75 m", a pretty recent version.  I'll update Chrome and see if I have the problem.

Comment: It looks like some versions of Chrome don't like it when INPUTs have a height of zero.  Try this jsfiddle for a workaround.  http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bc2/8/     I found a similar problem here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627531/input-slideup-slidedown-issue

Comment: so wait how can I incorporate this into my slide down.

Comment: Actually all I needed was <!DOCTYPE html> at top of page - no idea why but fixed it.

Comment: Hey I have a quick question do you have time?

Comment: Sweet.  If you want to look into a different method of 'showing' the inputs, you could try this. http://jsfiddle.net/9H3UE/  It should be more compatible with Chrome.

Comment: Sure, go to the javascript chat room.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15526/discussion-between-david-biga-and-davehale23)